# Are function scope static constexpr variable static storage duration

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, address-sanitizer

First I'll start by saying the question is maybe wrong, as I am not sure what is the issue with the following code.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct PixelRGB {
  T r {};
  T g {};
  T b {};
};
using PixelRGBui8 = PixelRGB<uint8_t>;

template <typename Pixel_T>
class FrameRowView {
  public:
  FrameRowView(const uint32_t& width)
      : m_width { width }
  {
  }

  const uint32_t& m_width;
};

double bar(auto& view)
{
  std::array<PixelRGBui8, 128> arrayA = {};
  std::cout << "width: " << view.m_width << " " << arrayA.data() <<  "\n";
  return 42.0;
}

void foo()
{
  static constexpr auto Width = 16;

  auto frameRowPrev = FrameRowView<PixelRGBui8> { Width };
  auto val = bar(frameRowPrev);

  std::cout << "frameRowPrev: " << frameRowPrev.m_width << "\n";
}

int main([[maybe_unused]] int argc, [[maybe_unused]] char* argv[])
{
  foo();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zYM71M37P)

Now the expected output is width: 16.

Clang in -O0 and -O3 output the right answer but in -O0 ASAN gives me an error about stack-use-after-scope.

> ==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7fe67e200040 at pc 0x55c0732b8ac1 bp 0x7fff5d95d590 sp 0x7fff5d95d588
>
> READ of size 4 at 0x7fe67e200040 thread T0
>
> ```
> #0 0x55c0732b8ac0 in double bar<FrameRowView<PixelRGB<unsigned char>>>(FrameRowView<PixelRGB<unsigned char>>&) /app/example.cpp:27:34
> #1 0x55c0732b8621 in foo() /app/example.cpp:36:14
> #2 0x55c0732b874a in main /app/example.cpp:43:3
> #3 0x7fe6807190b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x240b2) (BuildId: 9fdb74e7b217d06c93172a8243f8547f947ee6d1)
> #4 0x55c0731e137d in _start (/app/output.s+0x2137d)
> ```
>
> Address 0x7fe67e200040 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 64
> in frame
> #0 0x55c0732b84ff in foo() /app/example.cpp:32
>
> This frame has 2 object(s):
>
> ```
> [32, 40) 'frameRowPrev' (line 35)
> [64, 68) 'ref.tmp' (line 35) <== Memory access at offset 64 is inside this variable
> ```
>
> HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)

MSVC in /O0 output the right answer but in /O2 output garbage. Actually if you play with the size of the array named arrayA in the function bar and set it to 1 the output is actually good.

I am tempted to say it is a false positive on ASAN and a bug from MSVC?
But it could be my bug too.

Does anybody know the answer to this riddle?

Comment: Make it `static constexpr uint32_t Width = 16;`  You are trying to make a reference. Guarantee that it is a type match. [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/drTGGPjaa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `16` is `int` by default in C++ standard, `Width` is an `int` variable; then you pass it as a `const uint32_t&` parameter, so possibly it causes a copy to make a temporary `uint32_t` variable, and pass it to this `const` reference. After the function ends, this temporary variable is destructed, so your reference refers to an invalid variable, which causes undefined behavior.

See https://godbolt.org/z/GqzvYPW47, and as you make `Width` a `uint32_t` or an `int` variable, it will call different ctor for rvalue and const lvalue differ there.

If you make `Width` a `uint32_t` variable, it will be definitely right.

Comment: You are right, that is part of the issue, which beg more questions, why Clang worked?
Why this code `auto frameRowPrev = FrameRowView<PixelRGBui8> { Width };`doesn't give me an error because it shouldn't allow implicit conversion. Funny enough you remove the constexpr and you get that error.

Comment: @monamimani Nice questions and I think they're worth another post. The first question, I think that's because the behavior is undefined, so you cannot know what the compiler really does. If you check the assembly, Clang just uses `mov esi, 16` to represent the ctor, so you get the right answer; but in MSVC it's got from memory, so it's wrong.

Comment: @monamimani About the second question, you can check *Section Narrowing Conversion* [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), saying that: conversion from integer or unscoped enumeration type to integer type that **cannot represent all values of the original, except where source is a constant expression whose value can be stored exactly in the target type**. That's because `int` has negative numbers which cannot be represented by `uintxx_t`, and possibly you'll change it to a negative value in the future, so it's an error; However, `const` will not be so.